# How make a transaction from one node to another node on ropsten test network

Tags: web3js, blockchain, javascript, ethereumjs

i have used ethereumtx module to make a transaction on ropsten network but it showed me an error

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
web3 = new Web3();
const ethx = require("ethereumtx");

var privatekey = "*************************";

const details = {
    nonce:'0x4',
    gasPrice: '0x4a817c800',
    gasLimit: '0xdbba0',
    to: '0x5E06d211DD293366d39e02eaB693481e8C91b07C',
    value: '0x4000'
}

var rawtx = ethx.createrawtransaction(details);
console.log(rawtx);

var signtx = ethx.signrawtransaction(rawtx.rawtransaction,privatekey,rawtx.chainId);
console.log(signtx);

var validTransaction = ethx.verifyrawtransaction(signtx.signedTx, privatekey);
console.log(validTransaction);

var decodeTransaction = ethx.decoderawtransaction(signtx.signedTx);
console.log(decodeTransaction);
```

the error was

```
Error: Invalid signature v value
    at Object.module.exports.verifyrawtransaction (/Users/vivek/programming/blockchain/sample/node_modules/ethereumtx/index.js:233:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/vivek/programming/blockchain/sample/index.js:21:29)
```